# Why have steps when using ssqueezepy to calculate instantaneous frequency?

Tags: frequency, ssqueezepy

1. I'm using ssqueezepy to calculate signal's instantaneous frequency, The method like below:

```
from ssqueezepy import ssq_cwt, extract_ridges, TestSignals
signal = TestSignals(N=2048).lchirp()[0]
Tx, Wx, ssq_freqs, scales, *_ = ssq_cwt(signal, ('gmw', {'beta': 2, 'gamma': 3}), order=0, padtype='wrap', fs=100)
ridge_idxs = extract_ridges(Tx, scales, penalty=0.5)
frequencies = ssq_freqs[ridge_idxs[:, 0]]  # this is the result
plot(frequencies, ylims=(0, None), ylabel="Frequencies [Hz]", title="Frequency vs time, SSQ ridge", show=1)
```

2. The result like below:

- My signal's result
  [image: old image]
- Your signal's result
  [image: new image]
  You can see many steps in these two signal's results.

3. I think this method can get the correct result, but the result have some steps which not smooth.So what cause this?Which parameter should change?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (code I can run by pasting, with data if applicable).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I'm sorry for the late response.I have edit my code in question.And change the data to your sample data.But the result have steps also.So I think this may be some parameters to modify which like beta gamma and so on.